# jQuery to populate dropdown field

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

I can't get the following jQuery code to populate a list box. Are the syntax okay because it does not give me any error. I am sorry in advance if this is not the right place to post this.

```
NWF$(document).ready(function() {   
        NWF$().SPServices({      
            operation:"GetListCollection",
            webURL: (NWF$(this).attr("http://inside.ntb.com/teams/sales")),
            async:false,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                NWF$(xData.responseXML).find("StoreLocation").each(function(){
                    listTitle = (NWF$(this).attr("StoreNAME"));
                    listItem = "<option>" + listTitle + "</option>";
                    NWF$("#jsIdlstcoA").append(listItem);
                    console.log(NWF$(listItem));
                    alert(webURL);
                    alert(listTitle);
                    alert(listItem);
                });
            }
        });             
});
```

I can get following code to show version number under the console of the developer tool.

```
NWF$(document).ready(function(){
     console.log(NWF$().SPServices.Version());
});
```

Comment: How about posting the source of source file?

Comment: https://spservices.codeplex.com . All I did is change the last jquery to NWF

Comment: And what is the data format like in webUrl

Answer (score 0):

1) I would use GetListItems instead: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists

2) My example for appending select:

`$("select[title='FieldName']:first").append("<option value=" + index + " title=" + title + ">" + title + "</option>");`